# PHP form button requires two clicks to run

Tags: javascript, php

This form requires the 'add to basket' button to be clicked twice before it works.  The first click reloads the page, the second click adds it to the cart.

```
<form id="offerForm" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>">
   <input name="faction" type="hidden" value="addSpecialOffer">
     <? 
        /* 
        // Offer Key Here
        */
     ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="offerKey" value="<?=$offerKey;?>">
     <?
        /*
        // Offer Key Ends
        */
     ?>
   <button class="offerMonthly-buttonCTA">ADD TO BASKET</button>                
</form>
```

This is the PHP that is run:

```
<?
$faction=(isset($_REQUEST['faction'])) ? $_REQUEST['faction'] : '';
$specialOfferKey=(isset($_REQUEST['offerKey'])) ? $_REQUEST['offerKey'] : '';

if(IS_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER){
    $offerKey = "abcd1234-1234-1234-1234-12345678901"; 
}else{
    $offerKey = "abcd1234-1234-1234-1234-12345678901"; 
}
/*
** Check if offer is live - start
*/
$found = false;
$ok = $nwc->sendRequest("GetSpecialOffers", array("MaxNumber"=>"99","SpecialOfferPK"=>""));

if($ok && $nwc->success()){
    $offersArray=(isset($nwc->getValue('MySpecialOffers')->SpecialOffers->SpecialOffer)) ? $nwc->getValue('MySpecialOffers')->SpecialOffers->SpecialOffer : array();
    foreach($offersArray as $offer){
        if($offer->SpecialOfferPK == $offerKey){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found){
        header(sprintf("Location: %s", $locale->getLanguageURL("landing/expired/")));
        exit();
    }
}
/*
** Check if offer is live - end
*/
if($faction == "addSpecialOffer"){
    $ok = $nwc->sendRequest("UpdateShoppingCart", array("ProductCode"=>$specialOfferKey,"Quantity"=>1,"UpdateType"=>"Fixed"));
    
    if($ok && $nwc->success()){
        header(sprintf("Location: %s", $locale->getLanguageURL("cart/")));
        exit();
    }
}

$ok = $nwc->sendRequest("GetPageContent", array("PageName"=>"GenericLandingPage"));

if($ok && $nwc->success()){
}else{
    $locale->throwServiceError($nwc);
    exit;   
}

?>
```

What it should do is add the items to the cart on the first click.  I've tried using AJAX instead to call the script separately but this didn't work - the page just reloaded each time.
I'm relatively new to PHP so don't fully understand how this form works.

Comment: Nothing in this code would cause the behaviour you've described. Are there any JS events tied to this button and/or form?

Comment: I don't see Javascript. Why is it tagged under javascript?

Comment: @El_Vanja no there is no JS tied to this event.  It's simply the PHP shown above when the button is clicked

Comment: Do two refreshes happen, but the data is incorrect after the first one, or nothing happens after the first click? If it's the latter, PHP cannot be the source of this behaviour.

Comment: @El_Vanja nothing happens after the first click aside from the page being reloaded but there is no command for the page to reload which doesn't make sense to me

Comment: A form submission will reload the page, that's the default behaviour. This means the issue is somewhere inside your logic - apparently a condition isn't satisfied the first time. Just dump everything and find what doesn't hold the value that it should.

Answer (score 0):

use `<form onsubmit="return false" ...`
and `<button type="submit"`

and use ajax to handle add to basket functionality

Comment: Thank you - I tried this but still nothing.  Still didn't add anything to the cart.

Comment: is the cart functionality working itself?
my solution was for the first redirection so that we can isolate the cart functionality via ajax.